# Userform in Excel to control the flow of a macro

Tags: vba, excel, userform

This has got to be ridiculously easy, but I just cannot figure it out searching the web.

I have an Excel macro that performs various data entry/manipulation tasks. There is a point in the macro where I want the user to have the option of using data in column A or column B for calculations. All I want is to call a userform with two command buttons which pass their "true" or "false" value to the main macro and then perform "if" statements based on this information.

The trouble is I cannot get the userform to "tell" the macro anything. I'm sure this is a major noob question and I'm missing the method, but I cannot get this to work. Thank you!

**Edit, I've attached the  userform code below by request:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? It's hard for us to help troubleshoot without knowing what you're trying.

Comment: My code shouldn't make a difference in this case, I simply have function that manipulates some data and I only want a userform that alters 1 variable within that function so it runs differently. If it helps, I will attach my userform above.

Comment: Do not use Unload in the userform itself! The calling code is responsible for that. Use properties to tell the calling code about values you would like to return.

Comment: @Storax Thank you, I'm trying to understand userforms better and this helped. Are properties the .value of buttons in a userform?

Comment: Yes, amongst other thing. Just have a look at this introduction of a userform https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/ And you may also have a look at https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/

Comment: @Storax That's awesome, thank you! I had been calling values, but I think my problem was that I had been unloading the form within itself. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could avoid userform for that and use a simple message box:

```
If MsgBox("use data in column A or B [Yes=A, NO=B]", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    ' code for using data in column A
Else
    ' code for using data in column B
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for a helpful answer! I was not aware of this method and it solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: you are welcome. forums are there for such purposes as this one also...

Comment: I've spent a lot of time on MrExcel the past couple days :D